# How to unit test async/await example?

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit

Having been reading some [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) I found this post:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

With this example:

```
// My "library" method.
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}

// My "top-level" method.
public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
  var json = await GetJsonAsync(...);
  textBox1.Text = json;
}
```

How would one turn this code into an NUnit unit test to demonstrate the same solution to the same problem?

I have this code as a unit test but it does not behave the same as the interface example code - unless I am misunderstanding the piece.

```
// My "library" method.
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}

// My "top-level" method.
[Test]
public async void TestButton1_Click(...)
{
  var json = await GetJsonAsync(...);
  var gotOutput = json;
}
```

There is no assertion as that will come later.

Comment: What would you be testing in the above code? No need to make thing overly complicated. Make the test async and exercise the subject under test.

Comment: I want to demonstrate the deadlock as illustrated in the article but I don't see this happening when I place the example code into an unit test. I will modify the post to show what I think the unit test code would look like.

Comment: `TestButton1_Click` is most likely an event handler. Which is one of the cases where `async void` is actually allowed. In your test it is not an event handler but rather just a normal async void method which are fire and forget. Thus no assertion would be caught by the test harness

Comment: From the nunit point of view, it's pretty much impossible to say anything intelligent without knowing which version of the framework you are using. Async tests have been supported since 2.5.something but details have changed almost every release due to bug fixes.

Comment: NUnit Version 3.7.0

Comment: So it would appear that it is not possible to unit test this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two components to that deadlock: blocking on asynchronous code, and a single-threaded context.

The code sample you pasted does not block on asynchronous code (no `.Result`). It looks like you copied the sample that does *not* deadlock.

To reproduce the deadlock, you'd need to both block on the asynchronous code, and supply a single-threaded context. NUnit does have a single-threaded context that it applies in some scenarios. The details have changed a few times, but I'm pretty sure they ended up applying a context to `async void` methods, so I think this would deadlock:

```
[Test]
public async void TestButton1_Click(...)
{
  var json = GetJsonAsync(...).Result;
}
```

You can check to see if NUnit is supplying a context by reading `SynchronizationContext.Current` from a breakpoint in your test. If it's not, then you can supply a context yourself like the [`AsyncContext` in my `AsyncEx` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx):

```
[Test]
public void TestButton1_Click(...)
{
  var json = AsyncContext.Run(() => GetJsonAsync(...).Result);
}
```

Comment: Yes; My bad. I did indeed copy the non-blocking code. It was done in a hurry. I'm going to digest this before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to write a test in XUnit 2.4.0 that reproduced the deadlock following Stephen's pattern above.

What I have ended up doing is injecting an action into a mock component that asserts that the async code does not have a context:

```
mock.ValidationAction = () => Assert.Null(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

Indeed when running synchronously the context is populated, but when the async part is done in the thread pool (a layer of my code calls Task.Run(...)) the context is null.

I think this might serve to attest that the code will not run into deadlock, at least in that component and code path.